# Any open source backup software with NDMP support?

Tags: backup, open-source, ndmp

Is there any open source backup software with [NDMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NDMP) support?

I'm looking for open source software (or free software) for backing up a large NAS file server, which supports the NDMP protocol and uses the NDMP protocol for backup/restore. I was unable to find anything, yet...

Answer (score 2):

There's what looks to be a reasonable reference implementation at [ndmjob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndmjob/).  Shouldn't be too hard to shoehorn that into something workable with a few scripts.

Comment: It looks like it hasn't been updated since 2002, but if the manual is anything to go by, it looks like a *really* useful tool.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, Bacula. See http://wiki.bacula.org/doku.php?id=comparisons

Comment: seems to be only available in enterprise edition. but thank's anyway! i'll give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

Bareos appears to provide NDMP support in their basic open-source release.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it.

Freshmeat doesn't show any projects with ndmp in their names or description: (http://freshmeat.net/search?q=ndmp&submit=Search) and Bacula has been talking about supporting it since 2007 with nothing to show.

Sorry about your (and my) luck. A FOSS implementation of NDMP would be a big win for the enterprise community.

BTW, for anyone looking for more information on NDMP, the site of choice is http://www.ndmp.org/info/overview.shtml

Answer (score 0):

[NDMPCopy](http://www.ndmp.org/download/ndmpcopy/index.shtml)

[NDMP SDK](http://www.ndmp.org/download/)

There are some tools to use NDMP to a NetApp filer and there has been some limited testing with ZFS on OpenSolaris. Overall nothing as elegant as the commercial side.

Comment: It's too bad they don't seem to ship the sources.  It looks like it is solaris and HP/UX.  1999 called and wants their vendor support model back.